# How to know the path of Compass executable?

Tags: drupal, compass-sass

I am trying to use compass with Drupal 7, Basic theme and Compass module on my local hosting on Windows. It is already installed on my computer. Should i install it to my local webserver again, how can i know the path of existing Compass exutable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some more details would help get to the root of the problem:

1. Are you running compass from the command line, or using a GUI utility?
2. Did you install compass via `gem install compass` ?
3. What version of Windows are you running?

If you have properly installed ruby and compass, you should be able to `cd` into your drupal theme's directory and run `compass watch` to compile.

You can use the `where` command from the windows command prompt (`where compass` or, if that doesn't work `where ruby`) which will search your current directory and $PATH. If you cannot find compass, then you may need to reinstall compass/ruby.

Hope that helps!